# POST request in R: error in upload_file() with xml

Tags: r, xml, post

I'm trying to create a POST request, but the *body* parameter isn't working as I expected.

The POST_bodyRequest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <rs:alarm-request throttlesize="0"
 xmlns:rs="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/request"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/request ../../../xsd/Request.xsd ">
 <rs:requested-attribute id="0x10000"/> 
 <rs:requested-attribute id="0x10001"/> 
 <rs:requested-attribute id="0x10009"/> 
 <rs:requested-attribute id="0x1000a"/> 
 <rs:requested-attribute id="0x1006e"/> 
 <rs:requested-attribute id="0x11ee8"/> 
</rs:alarm-request>
```

The code, basically the POST call

```
xml <- upload_file("POST_bodyRequest.xml")
r2 <- POST(url, login.password, body = list(xml))
status_code(r2)
```

First thing to note is that the content from the file isn't saved in "xml" file:

```
> xml <- upload_file("POST_bodyRequest.xml")
> xml
Form file: POST_bodyRequest.xml (type: application/xml) 
> str(xml)
List of 2
 $ path: chr "D:\\MPM\\POST_bodyRequest.xml"
 $ type: chr "application/xml"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "form_file"
```

Therefore, the POST call returns an error

```
> r2 <- POST(url, login.password, body = list(xml))
Error: All components of body must be named
> status_code(r2)
[1] 415
```

I've also tried do read the xml file using *xmlParse()*. In this case, the code is recovered as expected, but I get the same error when calling POST.

```
> xml <- xmlParse(file = "POST_bodyRequest.xml")
> r2 <- POST(url, autenticacao, body = list(xml))
Erro: All components of body must be named
> xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rs:alarm-request xmlns:rs="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/request" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" throttlesize="0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.ca.com/spectrum/restful/schema/request ../../../xsd/Request.xsd ">
  <rs:requested-attribute id="0x10000"/>
  <rs:requested-attribute id="0x10001"/>
  <rs:requested-attribute id="0x10009"/>
  <rs:requested-attribute id="0x1000a"/>
  <rs:requested-attribute id="0x1006e"/>
  <rs:requested-attribute id="0x11ee8"/>
</rs:alarm-request>

> str(list(xml))
List of 1
 $ :Classes 'XMLInternalDocument', 'XMLAbstractDocument' <externalptr> 
> status_code(r2)
[1] 415
```

I had no trouble with GET requests in R. The POST request works fine with SoapUI. So, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are doing `body = list(xml)`. Should it not be `body = xml`?

Comment: I´ve also tried that, same result. EDIT: actually, the error message is different: "Error: Unknown type of `body`: must be NULL, FALSE, character, raw or list"

Comment: Did you try that with the `upload_file` version, or the `xmlParse` version? Seems like it should work with the former without the `list()`

Answer (score 0):

Well, it did work. The problem wasn't anything related to the upload_file() function or the xml file. It was the url variable, which wasn't updated to the POST version. I'd like to thank for the confirmations and check this issue as resolved.